# Sentiment Analysis By Date

Tags: r, group-by, sentiment-analysis, summarization

I'm doing some very basic sentiment analysis on a pretty large set of data that continues to grow every day. I need to feed this data into a shiny app where I can adjust the date range. Rather than running the analysis over and over again, what I'd like to do is create a new CSV with the sum of each sentiment score by date.  I'm having trouble iterating over the date though.   Here's some sample data and the `lapply()` statement I tried that is not working.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(syuzhet)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(date = c("2021-01-18", "2021-01-18", "2021-01-18", "2021-01-17","2021-01-17", "2021-01-16", "2021-01-15", "2021-01-15", "2021-01-15"),
                 text = c("Some text here", "More text", "Some other words", "Just making this up", "as I go along", "hope the example helps", "thank you in advance", "I appreciate the help", "the end"))

> df
        date                   text
1 2021-01-18         Some text here
2 2021-01-18              More text
3 2021-01-18       Some other words
4 2021-01-17    Just making this up
5 2021-01-17          as I go along
6 2021-01-16 hope the example helps
7 2021-01-15   thank you in advance
8 2021-01-15  I appreciate the help
9 2021-01-15                the end


dates_scores_df <- lapply(df, function(i){
  data <- df %>% 
    # Filter to the unique date
    filter(date == unique(df$date[i]))
  
  # Sentiment Analysis for each date
  sentiment_data <- get_nrc_sentiment(df$text)
  
  # Convert to df
  score_df <- data.frame(sentiment_data[,])
  
  # Transpose the data frame and adjust column names
  daily_sentiment_data <- transpose(score_df)
  colnames(daily_sentiment_data) <- rownames(score_df)

 # Add a date column
  daily_sentiment_data$date <- df$date[i]

})

sentiment_scores_by_date <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", dates_scores_df)
```

What I'd like to get to is something like this (data here is made up and will not match the example above)

```
      date anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative positive
2021-01-18     1            2       0    1   2       0        2     1        1        2
2021-01-17     1            2       0    2   3       3        1     2        0        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(syuzhet)

df %>%
  split(.$date) %>%
  imap_dfr(~get_nrc_sentiment(.x$text) %>% 
             summarise(across(.fns = sum)) %>% 
             mutate(date = .y, .before = 1)) -> result

result
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is not quite what I am looking for though.  I accomplished the same thing in a different way.  What I need is to iterate over the dates, and create a data table with the score totals for each day.

Comment: That is what my code is doing actually. I split rows by date and for each date apply `get_nrc_sentiment` function and combine the data into one dataframe.

Comment: Thank you.  I found the issue.  I copied your code directly into r studio in a new script with the sample data, and did not inlcude `library(syuzhet)`.  It works now.

Thank you for clarifying and for your help.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include the library. I edited the answer to include the library. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Function `lapply` iterates over elements of a list. Data frame is technically a list with each column as an element of that list. So in your example you are iterating over columns rather than rows, or even dates (that seems to be your goal). Instead of `lapply` I'd use `dplyr::group_by` in combination with one of: `dplyr::do`, `dplyr::summarize` or `tidyr::nest`. See documentations for each function to figure out which function suits the most your need.